# how to export csv file to LibreOffice' Calc?

Tags: csv, libreoffice, calc

Let's say I created a csv file and saved it somewhere.
How would I programmaticaly (using C++ if possible or something i could call from C++) open Calc with that csv file exported to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`system`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/):

```
 system("/path/to/calc /path/to/your/csv");
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

Comment: thank you very much! The idea is so simple i haven't even thinking about. I haven't thought that one could open calc simply by:


"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 4.0\program\scalc.exe" ExampleData.csv